# different between two time tags of HTML

Tags: php, html, time, tags, difference

i have this code in my html part

```
<input id="intime" name="intime" type="time">
<input id="outtime" name="outtime" type="time">
```

and in my PHP part

```
$t = $intime - $outtime;
```

the result of $t is equal to only the difference between hours what i need too is the difference between minutes e.g. (14:20 - 12:10 = 02:10)

Comment: What is the value of $intime and $outtime before the subtract?

Comment: @MeanGreen $intim = 09:00 and $outtime = 11:30

Answer (score 0):

php code

```
$diff = strtotime($intime) - strtotime($outtime);
echo date("h:i", strtotime($diff));
```

or you can try

```
$diff    = abs( strtotime( $intime) - strtotime( $outtime) );
$hours   = floor($diff/ (60*60)); 
$minuts  = floor($diff / 60);
```

Comment: first code give me a result equal to 1:00 even i change $intime and $outtime and the second code maybe give me right result but i have to fix it btw the result of $hours = 6 and $minuts = 360 whet $intime = 08:00 and $outtime = 14:00

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$firstTime = $_GET['intime']; // or POST
$secondTime = $_GET['outtime'];

list($firstMinutes, $firstSeconds) = explode(':', $firstTime);
list($secondMinutes, $secondSeconds) = explode(':', $secondTime);

$firstSeconds += ($firstMinutes * 60);
$secondSeconds += ($secondMinutes * 60);
$minute_difference = $secondSeconds - $firstSeconds; 
$hour_difference =  $difference/60;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ... the $difference give a result of 360 and i don't know what is that because i put the same minutes value in $firstTime and $secondTime ... anyway thank you for your reply because you gave me an idea to solve this problem and i will put it as answer ^_^  ... thank you

Comment: 360 means 360 minutes. (eg: 06:00 AM to 12:00 PM ). That is the difference between two times you input. I have add an edit to get the hour difference.
Anyway glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code and it solved my problem ...

```
$intime = explode(':',@$_POST['intime']);
$outtime = explode(':',@$_POST['outtime']);
$hours = (($outtime[0]-$intime[0])*60+($outtime[1]-$intime[1]))/60;
$hours = floor($hours);
$minutes = (($outtime[0]-$intime[0])*60+($outtime[1]-$intime[1]))%60;
echo $hours.":".$minutes;
```

thanks for all replies ^_^